# Pillow instillation field with python3.2 django1.8

Tags: python, django, pip, python-imaging-library

I'm working with a django project and now I want to add an image field, django asked me to install Pillow with the command "`pip install Pillow`", 
thie problem is when I run this command, and this one also "`sudo install Pillow`" I get the message:

```
gcc: error: build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.2/libImaging/BoxBlur.o: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3.2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-otvko5/Pillow/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-5430vf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-otvko5/Pillow
```

I have tried all the ways that I found on the internet as well as the other ways to install Pillow such as easy_install, but each time I get a new problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run the below commands in your linux

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Comment: when I run the second command I get this:

E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?

Comment: I fixed this I problem, I run all three commands but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`sudo apt-get install python-pil`

Comment: This command gave me no problem, but it doesn't seem to work. Because When I run this command: python3.2 manage.py syncdb or python3.2 manage.py migrate 

I get the same error: 

ERRORS:
blog.Entry.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
 HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow or run command "pip install Pillow".

Comment: Is your system 32-bit? If so then you `sudo apt-get insall python-pil:i386`. `python-pil` is a Pillow fork. It should work. What error `pip install Pillow` is showing? If you do not have  `pip`, then install it using `python get-pip.py` command.